# Perl Net::Appliance::Session waitfor?

Tags: perl

I have a problem with Net::Appliance::Session. I created a session, executed my command. After execution it prompts me some question (yes/no). I want to answer it but didn't find a way how to do it. Below you can see my trials:

```
$session->cmd($command);
$session->waitfor(Match=>'/.*yes*/');
$session->print("no");
$session->waitfor(Match=>'');
$session->print("y");
```

I don't know where is the problem. Accoding to CPAN documentations Net::Telnet have the method waitfor. But Session documentation tells that we can use waitfor(). Another thing said there is that the method "cmd" have a member Match which includes all the features of waitfor(). So I changed my code like below:

```
$session->cmd($command, Match=>'/.*yes*/');
$session->print("no");
```

Executing this reports below error:

> Odd number of elements in hash assignment at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Appliance/Session.pm line 245.

Is there any idea how can I do that? And why am I getting this error message?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Net::Appliance::Session](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aAppliance%3a%3aSession) page at [meta::cpan](https://metacpan.org/)

To handle more complicated interactions, for example commands which prompt for confirmation or optional parameters, you should use a Macro. These are set up in the phrasebook and issued via the `$s->macro($name)` method call. See the [Phrasebook](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aCLI%3a%3aInteract%3a%3aPhrasebook) and [Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aCLI%3a%3aInteract%3a%3aManual%3a%3aCookbook) manual pages for further details.

So you set up a macro (scripted call and response) in a phrasebook, and then tell your session to use that macro.

Comment: Can you please give me some precise code example? Because I've read all the documentations, but I couldn't put things together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no code to show you.  Did you set up a phrasebook? Did you call the phrase using the macro() method?